# Adding prefix to existing array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to add suffix to an existing `array`. Below is my code

```
print('a' + [10, 100])
```

With this I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Could you please help hoe to do that? I could use some `for` loop but I believe there may be more straightforward way to achieve the same.

Comment: The error message is clear. So you want a `string` as this - `a10`?

Comment: I want to get a new string array as `[a10, a100]`

Comment: Try this - `['a'+str(x) for x in [10, 100]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want a new string array (list).  You could try this:

```
new_lst = ['a'+str(x) for x in [10, 100]] # just use string concatentation
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new concatenated array as:

```
>>> ['{0}{1}'.format('a', num) for num in [10, 100]]
['a10', 'a100']
```

Read [String format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) and [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) from doc.